# Clear Cell contents depend on other cell content

Tags: excel, vba

My first post here, maybe someone will be able to help.

I have a large Excel table with data from labs. Some results are below LOD And I need to remove them as I do not need them.
So basically I need to clear data in one cell, say `E11`, if data in `D11` shows "<". Meaning below LOD.

If possible I would like to replace value in `E11` with "-".

Is there any one who could help me please.

Comment: please share the code. What you have tried so far?

Comment: I haven't use the code yet As I'm  new to VBA. I just learned that something Like VBA even exists. I am not looking for someone to do the work for me, but my wife asked for help (this is for her) and I am trying to help her. When I google this problem, I was send to this website couple of times when others had simmilar problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about this and you don't really need VBA.

**Without VBA** - Create a filter on your results and simply filter away the "<" - you could copy and paste this filtered table to another sheet

You could use a cell formula to help you identify results: `=IF(A1="<","",B1)` which would look at `A1`, if `A1` was a `<` then it'd return nothing, otherwise it'll return value in cell `B1`.

**With VBA** - you'd basically be applying the same logic, just written in code. If you really want to do this, then look up how to do a loop first and how to use IF logic...

Comment: Thank you, I have use filter option, however this would work if I would have only one set of results. Hence I have several sites results in one table this dose not work. I will look the loops now. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Is it possible to add excel file somewhere here so you can check what I work with?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLBUV.jpg)
This is the worksheet I work with. I would like to clear all the values where < is next to them. This is just part of much bigger table.