# Highlighting cells depend of other cell content

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I am still trying to solve my problem: [Clear Cell contents depend on other cell content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52516361/clear-cell-contents-depend-on-other-cell-content?noredirect=1#comment91972528_52516361)

However, this time I was thinking if is possible to highlight cells depending on what is in another cell.

Imagine I have two columns, one with symbol "N" or "<", and the other column with values. I need a way to mark all the values where "<" is in neigbouring cell.

I hope I not overcomplicate this:) Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why not just use neighbouringCell="<" as your conditional formatting rule? Use relative references.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that conditional formatting can get you there as I don't believe it accepts relative references.

You will likely need to use VBA

With little information provided I'll just assume there are 10 rows and you want to highlight column 2 based on column 1 in Sheet1:

```
for i = 1 to 10
    if Sheet1.cells(i,1).value = "<" then
        Sheet1.cells(i,2).interior.color = vbyellow
    end if
next i
```

Hope this helps